# Favicon not showing over SSL

Tags: html, favicon

My website favicon.ico is not showing when using SSL links. Seems to work fine with non-SSL.
But the problem is I have other two pages getting viewed over SSL that shows the correct favicon.

This is the favicon.ico link (works fine).
https://ricardoconceicao.com/favicon.ico

This is the link to the page.
https://ricardoconceicao.com/index2.html

Here is the code used:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a caching issue? Try hitting `CTRL` + `F5`, and also doing `SHIFT` + `CTRL` + `R` to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Done everything from clearing the cache and using Chrome & Firefox. Still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested your code and the link to the favicon isn't correct - this may be after following the suggestion that was made by another post on this thread.

Replace the current link rel tag you have on https://ricardoconceicao.com/index2.html

With

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

And it should work just fine, eventually. As others have mentioned, it may just be a caching issue. Either way, rest assured that you are not going crazy, because it definitely should be working. I went onto your page and edited the link rel tag in Chrome Dev Tools with the one I've mentioned in this post and the favicon appeared immediately. Anyway, hope that helps :)

Comment: I had already tried that and it failed. But it's working after clearing computer tmps/ and rebooting the system. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Give the full URL for favicon path. As follows

```html
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://ricardoconceicao.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: Try clearing your cache, or try a different browser maybe.

Comment: All pages favicon.ico are working fine except for this one. I've cleaned caches and everything.

Comment: Your favicon loads just fine on my end.

Comment: It doesn't work on my end, neither with Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Adding two dots before your current image path might do the trick. If not, then add the full path.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```